# RadGridView Template Selector

Tags: c#, xaml, telerik

I'm using a RadGridView to display a bunch of items in a grid. For each item, I want to switch between two different templates based on the data being given. One is a dependency property which essentially pops a text block in, the other is another RadGridView to display a table.

When put in statically, they both work individually, but I want to dynamically select these two different templates. My selector does not get called, however, and thus no template is used.

Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="theBasicView">
        <controls:InfoDetailsControl InfoDetail="{Binding InfoDetails}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="theTableView">
        <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding DetailsTable}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <analysis:DetailsTemplateSelector 
        BasicView="{StaticResource theBasicView}"
        TableView="{StaticResource theTableView}"
        x:Key="detailsTemplateSelector"
        />
</Window.Resources>
```

And the template selector in question:

```
<telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ItemsControl
               ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource detailsTemplateSelector}"
               />
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

If it is a BasicView, then the DetailsTable should be null. Otherwise, it should be a TableView. Here is my DetailsTemplateSelector:

```
public class DetailsTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate BasicView { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TableView { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container) {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
        if (element != null && item != null && item is ViewableRuleResult)
        {
            ViewableRuleResult ruleResult = item as ViewableRuleResult;
            Window window = Application.Current.MainWindow;

            if (ruleResult.DetailsTable == null)
            {
                return BasicView;
            }
            else
            {
                return TableView;
            }             
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Putting a breakpoint in the `SelectTemplate` function never gets hit. Why is my DetailsTemplateSelector never getting called? I have a feeling that the template selector in my RowDetailsTemplate isn't right. Let me know if you need more detail or something is unclear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. Turns out RadGridView has a property `RowDetailsTemplateSelector`. Using the following XAML:

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="resultsgrid"
                                RowDetailsTemplateSelector="{StaticResource detailsTemplateSelector}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding ViewableItems}"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                Margin="0,0,0,30"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                >
```

And completely deleting the `RowDetailsTemplate` previously defined, it now functions properly.